# exposing docker containers to internet

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file with some services, and for some of them specifically a spring boot application that I have it as a docker image I want to access it from outside the server that I installed the services on.

I added the ports as - 8080:8080 in docker compose but still I cannot access the port from outside the server I also used ufw to enable port 8080 and 8080/tcp, but still with no luck.
So am I missing anything else ?

my docker compose file is so simple:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  spring-boot-app:
    image: todorpashkulov/kafkalogger:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

here is the sudo ufw status result:

[image]

Comment: Need debug details. Output of `ufw status verbose` and `telnet`, `ss` / `netstat` results?

Comment: Could you also to share your whole ```docker-compose.yaml```? Here is mine for references: https://github.com/Gelassen/swap/blob/main/docker-compose.yaml

Comment: I added the docker-compose.yaml and the result for ufw status command

Comment: Which OS are you running the server on? Also can you do a `docker network inspect` of the network that compose creates and look up whether the gateway in there is mention in `ip route`?